# Calculate a hard limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate: $$
\lim_{x\to+\infty} x\left( \frac{1}{x^2+1^2}+\frac{1}{x^2+2^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{x^2+x^2}\right)$$

Comment: Transform it into a Riemann sum.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Do you have any ideas about basic techniques for calculating limits and whether they work or not on this specific case?

Comment: How? I have tried many times to solve this question.

Comment: $x$ is a natural number?

Comment: Yes, $ x $ is a natural number.

Answer (score 11):

Idea: change the limit in a Riemann sum.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n \Bigg( \sum_{k=1}^n {\frac {1}{n^2+k^2}}\Bigg) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac {n^2}{n^2+k^2}}\Bigg)= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac {1}{1+(\frac{n}{k})^2}}\Bigg)$$

$$=\int_{0}^1 {\frac {dx}{1+x^2}}=\arctan(1)-\arctan(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{=} \lim_{x\to+\infty} x\left( \frac{1}{x^2+1^2} + \frac{1}{x^2+2^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{x^2+x^2}\right) \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac 1 x \left( \frac{1}{1+\frac{1^2}{x^2}} + \frac{1}{1+\frac{2^2}{x^2}} +\cdots+\frac1{1+\frac{x^2}{x^2}} \right) \\[8pt]
& = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+w^2} \, dw = \frac \pi 4.
\end{align}
$$