# How find this $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{a_{n}+1}+\frac{1}{a_{n}+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n}+b_{n}}\right)=x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, integers

Prove that for any $x\in[0,\infty)$ there exist sequences of positive integers $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $\{b_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{a_{n}+1}+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}+2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}+b_{n}}\right)=x.$$

I only know this
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n+n}=\ln{2}$$

But for my problem I can't. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Note that (integral comparison test)
$$
\ln \big(\tfrac{\ell-1/n}{k-1/n}\big)
=\int_{kn-1}^{\ell n-1}\frac{dx}{x}<
\frac{1}{kn+1}+\frac{1}{kn+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\ell n}<\int_{kn}^{\ell n}\frac{dx}{x}
=\ln (\tfrac{\ell}{k})
$$
Let strictly increasing sequences of integers $k_n$, $\ell_n$, such that
$$
\frac{\ell_n}{k_n}\to\mathrm{e}^x.
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{(\ell_m-k_m)n}
\frac{1}{k_nn+j}\to x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Change the limit in a Riemann sum :-)

like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639611/calculate-a-hard-limit/639625#639625)

Comment: can you post your solution? why xsit sequences of nonnegative integers $\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\}$?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that any real number can be approximated arbitrarily closely by rationals. The numbers that you are looking for are any sequences such that:
$$e^x-1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}$$
(Can you see why? Hint: $H_n=\dfrac11+\dfrac12+\dfrac13+\dotsb+\dfrac1n\approx\ln n+\gamma$, and what you have above is $H_{a_n+b_n}-H_{a_n}$.)